# "Indicated on the map are two potential locations for a new supermarket in the town."

Tags: sentence-structure

Can someone explain the rule behind the below sentence structure? Especially the position of the auxiliary verb "are".

> Indicated on the map are two potential locations for a new supermarket in the town.

Answer (score 1):

It is a subject-adjective inversion. I would say that **are** is the main verb, not an auxiliary verb.

> Two potential locations [for a new supermarket in town] are indicated on the map.
>
> Indicated on the map are two locations [for a new supermarket in town].

Either option is acceptable. The inversion may be seen as more poetic or lyrical, and can be found in songs, [for example.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Is_the_Color_of_My_True_Love%27s_Hair)

Comment: I don't get that. Ignoring the syntactically irrelevant additional details, and unravelling the inversion, it's *Two locations **are Indicated**.* To my mind, the main verb there is the (passivised) past tense of ***to indicate***, and ***are*** is indeed an auxiliary verb.